# Is there a way to make two separate elements scroll with each other without any weird shaking on mobile?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Let's say I have two elements.

```
   <div class='scrollable'></div>
   <div class='scrollable'></div>
```

Both of these elements have items inside that are similar in width.
What I want is when one of these elements scroll the other should scroll with it at the same time without any lag or delay on all devices.

Here is what I've tried but still got lags specially on mobile:

```
 $('.scrollable').scroll(function (e) {
    $('.scrollable').not(this).scrollLeft(e.target.scrollLeft);
 })
```

So please help I really need it.

Comment: Why not put both your elements inside a single scrollable? On mobile you remove overflow scroll from the children and you add it to the parent :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you go for another solution:

```
<div class='scrollable-s'>
    <div class='scrollable-l'></div>
    <div class='scrollable-l'></div>
</div>
```

the `-s` (*small*) will be only scrollable on mobile
whilst the `-l` (*large*) will be only scrollable on larger devices like desktop.

You can put the logic inside your CSS `@media` rules.

```css
/* 0 to 899px */

.scrollable-s {
  overflow: auto;
}
.scrollable-l {
  overflow: visible;
}


/* 900px or larger */

@media (min-width: 900px) {

  .scrollable-s {
    overflow: visible;
  }
  .scrollable-l {
    overflow: auto;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work because one of the elements has position fixed